# Storing Dictionary of Dictionary in Redis (StackExchange.Redis)

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I want to store Dictionary of Dictionary in Redis. For e.g. I have Product, Order, Customer etc... business entity and they all have Id and other relevant properties.

I am using latest version of StackExchage.Redis C#

Expectation: 
1. When I Save product with ID 10 then it should first check if 
    Product type entity available 
    then check Product Id 10 present, If yes then return whole product.
2. Same for other entities. Id 10 may be available for Order entity as well.

Key: TypeName Value: Dict(int, Type)

whenever any writes happens, don't want to update whole dictionary, just want to add new record or update record in a dictionary.

So, 
 1. whenever all product are requested, i can return inner dictionary.Values 
 2. If individual product requested then i can return one Product
 3. If requested for all product deletes then it will delete everything in one go.
 4. Set time out for each ProductIds using HashSet?

Comment: It seems like you need a more lower lever hierarchical solution to store your data in Redis, you might want to consider using RedisJSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [Redis Hashes](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes). You can create hashes for products, order.. etc. and store each item by their key. here is an example:

- **adding product into hash/Dictionary**

```
    redis>  HSET product id:10 "{product_10_json}" id:11 "{product_11_json}"
    (integer) 2
```

- **retrive an individual product by id.**

```
    redis> HGET product id:10
    "{product_10_json}"
```

- **fetch all product list**

```
    redis> HGETALL product
    1) "id:10"
    2) "{product_10_json}"
    3) "id:11"
    4) "{product_11_json}"
```

- **Delete an item product list:**

```
    redis> Hdel product id:10
    (integer) 1
    redis> HGETALL product
    1) "id:11"
    2) "{product_11_json}"
```

- **TO delete all product just delete corresponding key**

```
    redis> del product
    (integer) 1
```

Edit: **Count the number of items in a key**:

> Is there any command which will give me total values count? like product has 15 records

You should use [HLEN](https://redis.io/commands/hlen)

```
redis>HSET product product1 "Hello"
(integer) 1
redis> HSET product product2 "World"
(integer) 1
redis> HLEN product
(integer) 2
```

Comment: Is there any command which will give me total values count? like product has 15 records.

Comment: Instead of asking here, it would be better if you create a new question and ask a specific question there. That way you will get more diversified and quick responses from the community. @Gopu_Tunas

Comment: How to set time out for each ProductIds?