# How can i find out time when my key is stored in Redis Cache/db?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Is there any redis command which tells when key is stored in redis?

I know there is TTL command.

Depending on time, i want to take different action. like if 
live since last 1 min then do x, 
live since last 2 min then do y,
etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such command. However, you can achieve your goal with the `EXPIRE` and `TTL` commands.

For each key, set its TTL to be `1000000000`, i.e. `EXPIRE key 1000000000`. So that the key will be expired after about `32` years. It's should be long enough.

When you want to find out how long the key has been stored, just get the key's TTL, i.e. `TTL key`. And the key has been stored since `1000000000  - TTL` seconds.

Comment: How to achieve this for Key value=HashENtry[] store?  Can i set time to expire for each hash entry? or whole key? In this example i want to store expire time for each entry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57308747/storing-dictionary-of-dictionary-in-redis-stackexchange-redis

Comment: NO, you cannot set expiration for each hash entry. Expiration can only be set on key. So if you want to achieve that, you should save each hash entry as a key-value pair, and key is `key:field`, value is the original hash value.