# How to get the redis key creation time with jedis?

Tags: redis, jedis

Is it possible to get the key creation timestamp in redis db using jedis?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i find out time when my key is stored in Redis Cache/db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57394260/how-can-i-find-out-time-when-my-key-is-stored-in-redis-cache-db)

Comment: No... currently the data entered in the redis cache I am using is having no expiry.

Answer (score 3):

**NO.** There is no such command/support in Redis. Jedis, being a Redis client, does not support this as well.